# Data interpolation in python

Tags: python, graph, plot, interpolation

I have four one dimensional lists: X1, Y1, X2, Y2.

- X1 and Y1 each have 203 data points.
- X2 and Y2 each have 1532 data points.
- X1 and X2 are at different intervals, but both measure time.

I want to graph Y1 vs Y2.

I can plot just fine once I get the interpolated data, but can't think of how to interpolate data. I've thought and researched this a couple hours, and just can't figure it out. I don't mind a linear interpolation, but just can't figure out a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# first data set
X1 = np.linspace(0,1,203)
Y1 = np.sin(X1)

# second data set
X2 = np.linspace(0, 0.5, 1532)
Y2 = np.cos(X2)

# get interpolated values of Y1 evaluated at X2
Y1_interp = np.interp(X2, X1, Y1)

# plot interpolated Y1 vs Y2
plt.plot(Y1_interp, Y2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use matplotlib, you can just call `plot(X1, Y1, 'bo', X2, Y2, 'r+')`. Change the formatting as you'd like, but it can cope with different lengths just fine. You can provide more than two without any issue.